# C 's format specifier

Tags: c, int

I have this code in C-

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a=90;
    float b=4;
    printf("%f",90%4);
}
```

It gives an output 0.0000,I am unable to understand why???
i know that 90%4 returns 2 and the format specifier specified is %f,which is for double,but what I expect is-
That it will give an error,but it is showing 0.0000 as output.
Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Why do you think it will throw an error?
Also, always use `int main()` with `return 0;`

Comment: because of type mismatch,format specifier is %f and value returned is int.

Comment: And if it will not show error,then why it is not displaying 2.0000

Comment: [`void main()` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714)

Comment: What's the point of the useless `a` and `b` here? Do you mean `printf("%f", a % b);`? That won't even compile as `%` can only operate on integer types

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc By the very link you provided, void main (void) is not necessarily wrong, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518). Making such comments about the form of main is not productive, especially when the comments are incorrect.

Comment: @Lundin of course I know `void main()` is valid in a freestanding environment. But do you think the OP's running one of them? Most questions that use `void main()` are from Indians who still use Turbo C

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It is not clear that void main() is forbidden even in hosted environments. The standard is not clear, it just says "or in some other implementation-defined manner" as was discussed in the linked answer, with references to the C rationale etc. The OP didn't specify any platform for his program, nor is the form of main relevant to the question. As for people who still use Borland Turbo, they won't listen to reason anyhow, so you might as well be talking to a wall.

Answer (score 6):

The *type* of 90%4 will be `int`.

The behaviour on using `%f` as the format specifier for an `int` is undefined.

The output could be 2, it could be 0. The compiler could even eat your cat.

Answer (score 5):

This discrepancy comes about because the compiler and library do not communicate regarding types. What happens is that your C compiler observes that printf is a variadic function taking any number of arguments, so the extra arguments get passed per their individual types. If you're lucky, it also parses the format string and warns you that the type doesn't match:

```
$ gcc -Wformat -o fmterr fmterr.c
fmterr.c: In function ‘main’:
fmterr.c:6:2: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, 
but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%f",90%4);
  ^
```

But this is still just a warning; you might have replaced printf with a function with different behaviour, as far as the compiler is concerned. At run time, floating point and integer arguments may not even be placed in the same place, and certainly don't have the same format, so the particular result of 0.0 is not guaranteed. What really happens may be related to the platform ABI. You can get specified behaviour by changing the printf argument to something like `(float)(90%4)`.

Answer (score 2):

`%f` expects a `double` and you pass `int(90%4=2)` in `printf`. Thus ,leading to *Undefined Behaiour* and can give output anything .

You need to *explicitly* cast -

```
printf("%f",(double)(90%4));
```

**Don't** try this as compiler will generate an error (as pointed by @chux Sir )-

```
printf("%f",90%(double)4);
```

Comment: The two versions aren't equivalent, as the first will perform the modulo calculation on two doubles, adding decimals if applicable, but also possibly adding floating point inaccuracy to the result. While the latter version will perform the calculation on integers.

Comment: @Lundin `printf("%f",90%(double)4);` is not even legal C code.  "invalid operands to binary % (have 'int' and 'double')"

Comment: @chux  I didn't compiled that. But it turns out it will make unhappy  .I will fix it

Comment: @chux Oh right, I had forgotten that in the specific case of the % operator the C standard enforces int. You'd have to use fmod() or some function like that.

Answer (score 2):

`printf` is a variadic function. Such functions are obscure, with no type safety worth mentioning. What such functions do is to implicitly promote small integer types to type `int` and `float` to `double`, but that is it. It is not able to do more subtle things like integer to float conversion.

So printf in itself can't tell what you passed on it, it relies on the programmer to specify the correct type. Integer literals such as `90` are of type `int`. With the `%f` specifier you told printf that you passed a `double`, but actually passed an `int`, so you invoke undefined behavior. Meaning that anything can happen: incorrect prints, correct prints, program crash etc.

An explicit cast `(double)(90%4)` will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In short: there is no error checking for format specifiers. If your format is looking for a double, then whatever you pass as an argument (or even if you pass nothing) will be interpreted as a double.

Comment: `%f` in printf looks for a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question!

Answer (score -1):

By default, `90%4` gives an integer.
If you print integer with `%f` specifier, it will print 0.

For example, `printf("%f", 2);` will print 0.

You typecast result with float, you will get 2.00000.

`printf("%f",(float) (90%4));` will print 2.00000

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: `printf("%f", 2);` will invoke undefined behavior, it may print anything. See all the other answers.

Comment: it will print 0, I bet on it.

Comment: How undefined is undefined behavior, do you think?

Comment: How much do you bet on the fully standards-compliant C compiler that I maintain printing 0?

Comment: Please check this in any standard compiler. I just gave try here (ubuntu gcc, g++). It prints 0.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your comment. What result you got? Please let me know.

Comment: On *your* machine, with *your* compiler, it prints 0.  Because the standard does not define what will happen with this type of argument mismatch, there's no guarantee that another compiler will generate the same result.  It might, but you can't depend on that.

Comment: Try`printf("%e", some_int);` (e not f) to get some insight to the undefined behavior you are experiencing.